# using mahout taste recommender engine how recommend gor new userId which is just entered in preference table of mysqljdbcdatamodel?

Tags: mahout

I am using mahout taste library for building recommendation engine,
I have manually stored userid itemid and rating in preference table which is datamodel to engine, now when new user comes i enter his itemid userid and ratings from code to table..

But when I see recommendation for new userid..i won get result...but for old ids i get..

Why so ...is it related somehow to neighborhoodSize and similaritymodel..

What have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the new user through the framework, rather than just inserting the entry in the table. It won't pick up new entries until you refresh() otherwise, and that takes a long time. Instead look at calling setPreference() with the new user and item instead.

Comment: How to do it from frameWork..I am doing it like this,**
     sql.execute "insert into userpreferences (userId,itemId,preference) values ($uId,$iId,$rating)"
sql.commit()**........Can u please tell me Clearly..or if any link for it.

Comment: :As u said i need to refresh..My code is,*MySQLJDBCDataModel dataModel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(dataSource,
 "userPreferences", "userId", "itemId","preference","rtime" );
    dataModel.refresh(null)*....Whivh collection to refresh?